# Wildcard subdomain in Homestead for WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, homestead, multisite, wildcard-subdomain

I am using homestead for my local development environment. I was trying to set up a wordpress multisite with wildcard subdomain. But wordpress cannot create subdomains in the homestead. Can anyone suggest any way to do it.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: wordpress tried to create random subdomain 178e5.multisite.test and failed.